# localhost в linux

Tags: opensuse, linux

Подскажите пожалуйста!! У меня ОС Linux Open Suse. Я установил Zend Server CE, откомпилировал PHP. Сервер запускается по адресу localhost:10081, а localhost:80 почему-то не работает.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В апаче это все редактируется в конфигах, увы как в зенде это делать незнаю

Comment: Аналогично, эта сборка просто включает в себя Апач.Так что ищем `httpd.conf` а в нем строку `Listen`

Answer (score 1):

В том, что:

1. 80 tcp порт уже занят (можно проверить так: sudo netstat -tanp)
2. процесс запускается от непривилигированного пользователя, потому порты < 1024 ему использовать не удается